# Split and cut string in C#

Tags: c#, string, split

pretty new to C# language. I have a string which is as follows:

```
  Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.1.204 (192.168.1.204), Dst: 162.159.242.165 (162.159.242.165)
```

There are two pieces of data contained within which are the 192.168.1.204 and 162.159.242.165. I am struggling to understand how I can take these two sets of numbers out and put them into different strings to use later.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Look at the documentation for string.Split and string.Substring

Comment: Regular expression, I guess.

Comment: That's what regular expressions are for. Read up on that.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: get the index of `(` and get till `)`. Simple

Comment: 192.168.1.204 occurs twice.  Which one do you want?

Comment: @Shaharyar `"192.168.1.204), Dst: 162.159.242.165 (162.159.242.165"`

Comment: You don't need regular expressions if you know the string will always look like this, with only the IP addresses changing. You can just use `var arr = str.Split(); var ip1 = arr[5]; var ip2 = arr[8];`

Comment: It looks like your actual task is analyzing a log (file) - did you already consider [LogParser](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24659) instead of reinventing the wheel?

Comment: @SamIam at first iteration it will extract first parenthesis, and so on.. I just guided him thats why didn't explain much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string looks like it's being broken down by sections that are separated by a `,`, so the first thing I'd do is break it down into those sections

```
string[] sections = str.Split(',');
```

IT looks like those sections are broken down into a parameter name, and a parameter value, which are seperated by `:`.  so I'd iterate over your sections, and break that down into name and value

```
string name = sections[i].Split(':')[0];
string value = sections[i].Split(':')[1];
```

now your value has a little bit more than just an IP address, so you can use a regular expression to extract the first thing that looks like an ip address

```
var address = Regex.Match(value, @"\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+").Value;
```

You can also make use of the `name` string to determine which sections represent `Src` and which ones represent `Dst`

---

Now be careful with this.  That regex that I gave you will match invalid IPs such as `300.19028.38.1`  You can put a bit more effort than I did into getting a better regex if you're afraid of matching things that are not IP addresses.

Also, if you have extra unexpeced `,` or `:` in your string, then this logic is rendered invalid.

Answer (score 0):

here is how you do it using Regex:

```
public List<string> getIP(string myString)
    {
        List<string> myString = new List<string>();
        // use Regex.Matches to get all the string parts that match for an IP adress
        MatchCollection matchs = Regex.Matches(input, @"\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        //collect all the strings that matches
        foreach (Match match in matchs)
        {
            output.Add(match.Value);
        }

        //finaly! return the result as a list
        return output;
    }
```

you just give the function your string **input** and it will return all ip adresses within it
that you can access using thier indices .
hope that helps.